# How to fix Gradlew Errors (eas build)

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, build, expo

I am attempting to get my expo project to the app stores, but I am unable to build the Android App Build. This is because the build process keeps failing during the `Run Gradlew` step, saying that `android.content does not exist.` Great-- sounds like I either need to add `android.content` somewhere or delete it from somewhere. Only issue is that apparently I'm the only person on Earth ever to have this issue, as I can find absolutely no help online on where to go, what to do, or anything else that seems helpful. Could someone please share the solution?

Comment: Are you running managed or bare workflow? For my bare workflow, I had to delete my `/android` directory. Was having a similar issue and it worked for me.

Comment: It was managed. I ended up having to rebuild the whole app. I created a new expo app and just copied all of the files over.